# Is the SHA1 hash of a commit node the same on the source and target repositories after a push?

Tags: git, git-push

Suppose I clone a repository from some remote `r`, perform a commit, and push the changes up to `r`. Is the SHA1 hash of the new commit node the same in `r` as it is in my repository?

Comment: Yes. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106996/git-what-is-a-git-commit-id

Comment: If it wasn't, it would be hard to figure out if the two repos are in sync or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you push? Yes. IDs would be the same (and, therefore, their content and history).