# How to extract the commit ID alone from the full commit message in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I tried fetching only the commit ID from the commit message in the shell script, I need only "d1099308a1af0f91e93bf22cf6e9b5d294cf121d"

commit_message = "commit d1099308a1af0f91e93bf22cf6e9b5d294cf121d Author: Martin  Date: Wed Apr 17 16:05:35 2019"

I tried using the following sed command, but it is not working
commit_ID=$( sed -e 's/commit .(*) Author/' $commit_message )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like that?

```
sed 's/^commit \([^ ]*\).*/\1/' <<< $commit_message
```

**output**

```
d1099308a1af0f91e93bf22cf6e9b5d294cf121d
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have other ID's, [**this regex**](https://regex101.com/r/BHVDbz/1) will work:

```
[0-9a-fA-F]{20,}
```

If there are other ID's, then adding [**a look behind**](https://regex101.com/r/BHVDbz/2) will help filtering:

```
(?<="commit\s)[0-9a-fA-F]{20,}
```

However, the "s" command of sed does not fetch, it "substitutes". For fetching, you may want to use "grep" or others.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to:

```
egrep -o "[a-f0-9]{40}" log.txt
```

This will return only the git commit ID [SHA-1 hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29107504/1135424) (40 digits long).