# regex exactly match the short commit id in string

Tags: regex

like strings lines below,  i want to match the the string which must have 1 number and letter(short commit id).

```
online-release-0202-c3764ab8-02022329     #i need c3764ab8  
online-release-0202-02022329-c3764ab8     #i need c3764ab8
```

I tried the following rules, but it always matches a string of pure numbers

```
(?=([a-f0-9]{8}))
```

Comment: Your requireqments are not clear. Your sample `c3764ab8` has 5 numbers and 3 letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the *commit id* must has at least one digit and one letter `a-f`

Try this regex:

```
(?!\d{8}|[a-f]{8})[a-f\d]{8}
```

- `(?!\d{8}|[a-f]{8})` negative lookahead, the following 8 characters are not formed only by digits or letters `a-f`
- `[a-f\d]{8}` match 8 characters that are digits and `a-f`

Check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/0tPtCh/1/)

---

If you're checking a [git commit id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106996/what-is-a-git-commit-id), this rule doesn't always apply. It's an SHA hash that can be formed with pure numbers or `a-f`. Thus `02022329` is also a legal git commit id.

It is better to make your naming convention consistent to eliminate ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

You might also assert a char a-f and a digit using a positive lookahead `(?=` and then match 8 times either one of them using word boundaries `\b` to prevent a partial match.

```
\b(?=[0-9]*[a-f])(?=[a-f]*[0-9])[a-f0-9]{8}\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?=[0-9]*[a-f])` Positive lookahead, assert a char a-f
- `(?=[a-f]*[0-9])` Positive lookahead, assert a digit 0-9
- `[a-f0-9]{8}` Match 8 times either a char a-f or a digit 0-9
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TYkxBR/1)