# Will Git commits with incorrect dates in the future overwrite future work?

Tags: git, github

[image]

Hello,in my project I have a payroll system and sometimes I had to change my computer's date in order to test if my system works well, now as you can see I have made 2 previous commits on future dates, my question is what happens when these dates come? Will it override my commits?
Because 23 sep and 23 October were supposed to be 23 August, and I have made much much more commits after these two.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it. You can also check if your code uploaded to github in master is the current state of your project, with those commits and the ones you did after too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens when these dates come? Will it override my commits?

No! Each commit is identified by an [unique hash-code](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) based [on the actual content plus some metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106996/what-is-a-git-commit-id) (like the IDs of the parent commits).

---

You could consider to change the date of the commits:

[How can one change the timestamp of an old commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git/49708822)

Comment: Thanks for the short summing up answer! Much appreciated.