# How to amend last commit without losing commit tag

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

I have a commit with a tag, but when I amend any changes to it, it loses the tag.
I am not new to git, but still can't understand how it works

I've tried:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
git commit --amend --no-post-rewrite
git commit --reuse-message=HEAD -C HEAD
```

Comment: A tag is a pointer to a hash. So you’ll have to retag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commits cannot be rewritten. You can only make new commits and replace the old. See [my answer to What is a Git commit ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106996/what-is-a-git-commit-id) to understand why.

If you have this...

```
A - B - C [HEAD][tag]
```

After you commit amend, you have this.

```
A - B - C [tag]
     \
      C1 [HEAD]
```

A brand new commit with its own commit ID. Git does not move the tag for you.

You could write a little script which checks if the current commit has any tags (`git tag --points-at`), amends, and then moves the tag to the new commit for you (`git tag -f <tag>`). You can then call this `git-commit-amend` (so long as it's `git-something`), place it in your PATH, and it will be available as `git commit-amend`.